# Sum of gamma-ish power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I'm wondering if there is a nice closed-form expression for the sum
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^{-\alpha} x^n, \quad \alpha \in (1,2), \; x \in (0,1) $$
This is a power series with coefficients $a_n = n^{-\alpha}$, and I know how to handle this for $\alpha = 1,2$ by using the integral trick
$$ \log(1-x) = -\int \frac{1}{1-x} dx = - \int \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n \right) dx $$
and so on, but I'm not sure how to proceed for $\alpha \in (0,1)$. Is there an obvious way to sum this series? It kind of looks like a discrete version for the gamma integral, but not quite:
$$\Gamma(t) = \int_0^{\infty} x^{t-1} e^{-x} dx$$

Comment: See [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Comment: The sum should start at $n=1$. In such a case, your series is just $\text{Li}_{\alpha}(x)$.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks to the both of you.